# Format number with a total fixed number of digits

Tags: python

I need to have a decimal number formatted with an exact number of digits, counting both digits on the left and right of the decimal point.

Example with 5 digits:

- 1.0000    (1 digit left + 4 digits right)
- 10.000    (2 digit left + 3 digits right)
- 100.00    (3 digit left + 2 digits right)
- 1000.0    (4 digit left + 1 digits right)

I can define a fixed number of decimal points by doing

```
'{:.4f}'.format(my_num)
```

or in f-string notation

```
f'{my_num:.4f}'
```

But this is not what I want. I don't want a fixed number of decimal points, I want a fixed number of total number of digits, or if you like, that numbers have the same string length)

I can calculate the number of decimal points needed doing

```
n_decimals = 5 - len(str(int(my_num)))
```

But then I'm not sure how to specify the number of digits from a variable

```
f'{my_num:.{n_decimals }f}'   # doesn't work

f'{:.{my_num}f}'.format(my_num)  # doesn't work either
```

Besides, having to calculate the number of decimals by converting to int, then string, then calculating the length is hacky.

Is there a way to achive that?

Comment: What do you mean by `f'{my_num:.{n_decimals }f}'   # doesn't work` ? It should work

Comment: Use `g` specifier

Comment: Yeah, it works for me too (python 3.11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice the output?

```
>>> '{:.10f}'.format(1)[:6]
'1.0000'

>>> '{:.10f}'.format(10)[:6]
'10.000'

>>> '{:.10f}'.format(100)[:6]
'100.00'
```